# TableView content disappearing when adding method to a class

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Usual behavoir of my application is this: I have a class that both holds the custom object, and methods that create ObservableList (and corresponding TableView), so that those could be used in other classes. This works fine:

[image]

But soon as I add a method to that class, that **is empty**, and **isn't even used**, e.g.

```
public static void foo(){
}
```

..TableView turns into this:

[image]

At first I thought that it somehow interferes with the class that is meant to only hold objects, but then I realized that I added other, unrelated methods before, and it didn't affect the behaviour. So what exactly is happenning here?

This is myobject class (notice the TableView methods):

```
public class Proizvod implements Serializable {
String name;
String jedinicamere;
Double cena;
static ObservableList<Proizvod> proizvods;
static TableView izmenaProizvodaTable;

public Proizvod() {
    name = "";
    cena = 0.0;
}


public Proizvod(String name, double cena, String jedinicamere) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cena = cena;
    this.jedinicamere = jedinicamere;
}


public Double getCena() {
    return cena;
}

public void setCena(Double cena) {
    this.cena = cena;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getJedinicamere() {
    return jedinicamere;
}

public void setJedinicamere(String jedinicamere) {
    this.jedinicamere = jedinicamere;
}

public static TableView getTable() {


    proizvods = InputOutput.loadProizvods("proizvods.sav");

    izmenaProizvodaTable = new TableView(proizvods);

    TableColumn<Proizvod, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Ime");
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    TableColumn<Proizvod, String> cenaColumn = new TableColumn<>("Cena");
    cenaColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cena"));

    TableColumn<Proizvod, String> jedinicaColumn = new TableColumn<>("Jedinica mere");
    jedinicaColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("jedinicamere"));

    izmenaProizvodaTable.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, cenaColumn, jedinicaColumn);
    return izmenaProizvodaTable;
}

public static void newProizvod(Proizvod proizvod) {
    proizvods = InputOutput.loadProizvods("proizvods.sav");
    proizvods.add(proizvod);
    izmenaProizvodaTable.setItems(proizvods);
    InputOutput.saveProizvods(proizvods, "proizvods.sav");
}

public static void deleteProizvod(){
    ObservableList<Proizvod> productSelected, allProducts;
    allProducts = izmenaProizvodaTable.getItems();
    productSelected = izmenaProizvodaTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
    productSelected.forEach(allProducts::remove);
    InputOutput.saveProizvods(proizvods, "proizvods.sav");
   }
}
```

And this is the implementation:

```
    public static void unosProizvoda() {

    TableView tableView = Proizvod.getTable();
    TextField kolicina = new TextField();
    kolicina.setPromptText("Količina");

    Button dodajProizvod = new Button("Dodaj proizvod");
    dodajProizvod.setOnAction(event -> {

        Proizvod izabranProizvod = (Proizvod) tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        Main.addToOdredjeniProizvods(new OdredjeniProizvod(Integer.valueOf(kolicina.getText()), izabranProizvod));
        Main.enableFinalizeButton();
    });

    HBox hBox = new HBox(10, kolicina, dodajProizvod);
    hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    VBox vBox = new VBox(tableView, hBox);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 300, 400));
    stage.setTitle("Unos proizvoda");
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    stage.showAndWait();
}
```

Comment: Please edit to include an MCVE that shows the empty table.

Comment: The code you gave us is not executable. A MCVE should be executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was an issue with loading the object: object can only be correctly loaded if previously saved object has the exact same methods as the current one, e.g. if I save the object with `foo()` and `bar()`, and then delete the `bar()`, I won't be able to load that object. In the same way, **if I add another method** (the issue of the question), I again won't be able to load the object.

I didn't make Exceptions print out when they occur, so that's probably why I couldn't realize where's the issue. Point of the story, always print your Exceptions.